# Changing shape or shadow of icon or removing it completely

Tags: android, icons, shadow

Does anyone know how to get rid of the icon shadow? or at least change its shape? I thought first that it was touchWiz thing, but then I checked other icon and they seem to have different shaped shadows.

Here is the image to clarify what I mean:

[image]

and here is the icon I am using:

[image]

Comment: How is the icon being drawn?  XML, `ImageView` source, extended `View`.  Also is it a `Drawable` or a `Bitmap`?

Comment: android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher, it is drawable

Comment: and also it happened after I changed icon

Comment: So is there an `ic_launcher.xml`?  The drawables folder can contain XML and bitmaps and a `Drawable` will be an XML file.

Comment: @techiServices: He says in the question that it is a png

Comment: android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher code is from AndroidManifest.xml and ic_launcher is Drawable.

Comment: i think that shadow is left from previous icon

Comment: @Joel Sjögren.  png isn't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @techiServices: it is the extension of the icon image he provides in the question

Comment: I suspect that it is a default shadow because it is a launcher icon.

Comment: I tried to create new project and use this icon, and it works perfect. no shadows no nothing. So it definitelly is shadow of old icon. but I have no idea how to get dir of it

Comment: @Joel Sjögren.  There is no extension mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove the app from the device completely, clean the project and run it again. It has nothing to do with your drawable. I think it is some sort of cache.